# how to fix cannot find method onLoginButtonClick in binding compoment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, binding, android-databinding

I am  stuck in finding a solution to cannot find method onLoginButtonClick or in general android data binding bugs I want to make authentication in my app by using binding and room so this is my code

register layout

```
android:text="@{register.emailEditTextRegisterContext}"
android:text="@{register.passwordEditTextRegisterContext}"
android:onClick="@={()-> register.onButtonLoginRegisterClick(register)}"
android:text="@{register.confirmPasswordTextContext}"
android:text="@{register.nameRegisterContext}"
```

login layout

```
android:text="@{login.emailEditTextContext}"
android:text="@{login.PasswordEditTextContext}"
android:onClick="@={() -> login.onLoginButtonClick(login)}"
```

registerViewModel

```
private val _nameRegisterContext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val NameRegisterContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _nameRegisterContext

private val _emailEditTextRegisterContext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val emailEditTextRegisterContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _emailEditTextRegisterContext

private val _passwordEditTextRegisterContext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val passwordEditTextRegisterContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _passwordEditTextRegisterContext

private val _confirmPasswordTextContext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val confirmPasswordTextContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _confirmPasswordTextContext

private val _registerCompleted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val registerCompleted: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _registerCompleted

fun onButtonLoginRegisterClick(view: View){

}
```

login layout

```
private val _emailedittextcontext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val emailEditTextContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _emailedittextcontext

private val _passwordedittextcontext = MutableLiveData<String>()
val PasswordEditTextContext: LiveData<String>
    get() = _passwordedittextcontext

fun onLoginButtonClick(view : View){
        onLogingin()
    }
```

error(whenever I tried a solution it changes)

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method onButtonLoginRegisterClick(com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.register.RegisterViewModel) in class com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.register.RegisterViewModel
file:C:\Users\mehmet\Desktop\andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-with-recyclerview\app\src\main\res\layout\register_layout.xml
loc:87:32 - 87:81
****\ data binding error ****
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method onLoginButtonClick(com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.login.Login_ViewModel) in class com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.login.Login_ViewModel
file:C:\Users\mehmet\Desktop\andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-with-recyclerview\app\src\main\res\layout\login_layout.xml
loc:76:32 - 76:68
****\ data binding error ****
```

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although answer posted by @Miller Go Dev corrects your code somewhat, it still doesn't satisfy the needs.

The correct way would be this,

```
android:onClick="@={(view) -> login.onLoginButtonClick(view)}"

android:onClick="@={(view)-> register.onButtonLoginRegisterClick(view)}"

    //pass the view parameter to their respective method
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong:**

```
android:onClick="@={() -> login.onLoginButtonClick(login)}"
```

```
android:onClick="@={()-> register.onButtonLoginRegisterClick(register)}"
```

You are passing ViewModel object to these functions, not View as you want

**Right:**

```
android:onClick="@={(view) -> login.onLoginButtonClick()}"
```

```
android:onClick="@={(view)-> register.onButtonLoginRegisterClick()}"
```

**Ref:**
[Listener Binding in official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings)

Answer (score 0):

well, all I did to fix is to remove the = sign to make the data binding one-way

Wrong:

```
android:onClick="@={() -> login.onLoginButtonClick(login)}"
```

Right:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLoginButtonClick()}"
```